# Microsoft Graph API permissions in case of retrieving my own user profile

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to invoke the `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` HTTP endpoint, but it is not obvious what API I need to grant to my application in order to have sufficient privileges for the given API call. It is also not clear, how the type of the current user impacta this HTTP call (is the user a member of the organization, or a guest user, etc.).

This is the page i was trying to pull information from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `/me` it is enough to grant `User.Read` permission, which is AFAIK the minimal permission possible for an app, it is "Sign In" basically. It is supported for all types of accounts (both "organization" and "external" accounts)

There is also a handy graph explorer tool, which shows which grants are required for which graph APIs. They are also [well documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference).

The graph explorer tool:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

[image]